# make all the <li> elements inside a container <ul> element the same width

Tags: html, css

I've been struggling with this for a day or so now and I've gone back and started from square one a couple of times but I'm trying to get a horizontal css flyout header to work as I want.

The dropdown bit I want to expand as wide as needs be (it'd be great if the category names were forced to be on one line) while the container expands to accommodate them. A fiddle will explain better.

http://jsfiddle.net/HyuLy/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few `width: 100%`'s that are ruining your layout because of your `padding`'s.  `width` is the inside width of the element, so when you combine `width:100%` with, let's say, `padding:20px` your element is now 100% + 40px.

Also, you have a few `float: left`'s that shouldn't be there as well.  If you're stacking the elements vertically still, there's no need to `float: left`.

Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/scrimothy/mxW4y/

Since there's so much going on here, you may want to copy this css back into your text editor to see it better.  I've removed a few widths and floats

Comment: hey there, this looks indeed like what I want, thanks very much :)

Comment: No problem.  Hope the rest of your project works out well.  If this solution worked for you, you can accept it.  Or if you had any other questions about it, feel free to followup.  Thanks and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To make all the `<li>` elements inside the `<ul>` container the same width add this:

```css
div#dropMenu ul.level2 li {width: 100px;}
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for that but that doesn't do exactly what I want. It does make the li's all the same width but I want them at least fill the width of the container, and if possible for the container to get wider to accommodate whatever length the category name is (pref on one line)

Answer (score 0):

change code to the following to fill the `<li>` element inside the `<ul>` but this will not re-size the container `<ul>` to get wider to accommodate the `<li>`.

```css
.subCatodd{
    background-color:#7b631d;
    padding:10px 0;}
.subCateven {
    background-color:#665011;
    padding:10px 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this

http://jsfiddle.net/XUj5S/

When you start **adding** padding to 100% width it will be doing exactly that, that's why your li objects start to overlay their parents they are not 100% they are like 110% cuz of the padding you're adding, here's an example of what I'm saying...

http://jsfiddle.net/EcENF/

You have to define width on px if you start to add padding based on px, using % will just mess up things